# Can't set correct resolution

Tags: nvidia, hardware

OS: Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS; kernel: 4.4.0-51-generic; video card: Nvidia GeForce 6600 GT; video card driver: 304.132.

nvidia-settings program does not list the resolution I want for my monitor. I have tried using xrandr but it insists on adding the new resolution to the wrong output.

Comment: If you run `sudo nvidia-xconfig` from a terminal and let it create a new `xorg.conf` file, when you reboot after that, does it let you choose a different resolution?

Comment: No, I still can't choose the resolution I want.

Comment: Can you edit your question and give the output of `xrandr` from a command prompt?

Comment: I wish I could but I've had success by tweaking an old xorg.conf file that was lying around in my /etc/X11 directory, pinched from an older OS on my system (should I paste a copy here in case it might help someone else?) The resolution I have been wanting is now listed and can be successfully used in the nvidia-settings app/xrandr. Unfortunately, I now have the problem of not being able to get the correct resolution on my SDTV (TwinView cloning) or I get only output on the TV but not my monitor or vice versa.